# how do I capture a video square like instagram and vine using Mediarecorder

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have tried by setting the **videosize(width,height)** for mediarecorder, but this has device compatibility issue, on few devices its crashing at **mediarecorder.start();**

Comment: [link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) refer this link for ffmpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [the device happens to support a square video size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29), you are welcome to use it. Most will not.

Vine, based on the last reports that I heard, does not use `MediaRecorder`. Instead, they use preview frames from the camera, which they crop to be square and assemble into a video. I do not know what Instagram does.

You are also welcome to record a non-square video, then post-process the video yourself to crop it to be square.